# How to fix Microsoft OneDrive synchronization errors?

Tags: onedrive

How to fix Microsoft OneDrive synchronization errors?[image]

One thing I'm really confused about is that those two file names do not have the claimed special characters AFAICT.

Comment: You mean changing file name from `古代军旅常识` to `foobar古代军旅常识`? What a unreasonable requirement for Microsoft software.

Comment: Tried the solution without success.